# How to count content with SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, count

with

```
SELECT COUNT(column_name)
FROM table_name
WHERE condition;
```

I can count how many rows have a specific value but how is it possible to count within a cell?

Example:

In a cell I have the following input:

```
PossibleValues:
  English: yes
  German: yes
  Swedish: yes
TranslatableValues: '0'
```

Now I would like to count how many possible values does the cell store (3 in this case). Is this possible if yes how?

I'm looking forward for your answers.

Comment: Incorrectly stored data causes such problems.

Comment: GROUP BY is what you want!

Comment: update your question  add  a proper data sample and the expected  result  ..

Comment: do you need used data length of field right ?

Answer (score 0):

The possible values the cell could store is purely depending upon ur column size and datatype .
if suppose my column has a datatype-varchar(5),I will be able to store only 5 characters not more than that.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I dont think this is what the OP was talking about I am afraid

Comment: @RiggsFolly,Possible Values does cell store in the sense i meant that.Question might be much clear.

Comment: Thats possible bytes or chars, not does it store `English: yes German: yes Swedish: yes`

Answer (score 0):

If you want the distinct count of a column  then use  count distinct

```
SELECT COUNT(distinct column_name)
FROM table_name
WHERE condition;
```

Comment: I think OP is trying to ask how to count the content of a text column i.e. the number of `English: yes   German: yes   Swedish: yes` in a specific cell (text string)

Comment: @RiggsFolly    Could be, my answer is in this sense an attempt to make and so that OP can be explained better and an example can help him

Answer (score 0):

You can directly count data type's field length like

```
SELECT COUNT(distinct column_name)
OR
SELECT LENGTH(column_name) AS test FROM table_name;
```

also

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(field) AS tot_true, 
    COUNT(*)-COUNT(field) AS tot_false
FROM table
WHERE field=1
```